# How to set HttpListener Class's server root path?

Tags: c#, httplistener

I am using HttpListener Class to produce a local web server. But by default, HttpListener Class will read the path which saves HttpListener exe file.

If I want to set a different path as server root path, just like Apache can choose a root path, how to do it with HttpListener?

I have read the HttpListener document, but there is no method for doing this.

Thanks

Water Lin

Comment: By "root path" - do you mean "on the file system" (i.e. `c:\mywebapp\files`? or do you mean "the http path" (i.e. `http://foo/bar/blap/blop/` )?

Comment: wait a minute, httplistener is supposed to listen to http requests - no paths are involved in that process. Do you mean the addresses the listener will listen to? that has nothing to do with Apache's(or IIS) root path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But by default, HttpListener Class will read the path which saves HttpListener exe file. "

`HttpListener` has very little interest in local paths *at all*. Do you mean "my own code is defaulting to the working directory"? If so, this could simply just a case of

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(rootDirectory);
```

Although actually, frankly I'd just expect this to be done by keeping a `string rootDirectory`  (or maybe a `DirectoryInfo`) kicking around, and working *relative to that*.